# Gnome software centre crashes in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, software-center

I just fresh installed Ubuntu 16.04.1. Then I update the system and language.
After that when i open software it opens and crashes.

I try to open it through the command line but it throws this error:

```
$ gnome-software

(gnome-software:6730): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered    
(gnome-software:6730): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered    
(gnome-software:6730): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered    
(gnome-software:6730): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered    
(gnome-software:6730): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered    
(gnome-software:6730): GLib-ERROR **: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-software
sudo apt-get install gnome-software
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also getting this issue with my brand new XPX13 Ubuntu 16.04.

`gnome-software` works fine after being launched, but after a while starts stalling when looking for packages.

I found out that killing and restarting it fixes the issue. (just quitting is not enough)

```
$ ps aux |grep software
emmanuel  2047  1.0  2.5 1863956 208864 ?      SLl  avr08  15:26 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service
root      3197  0.0  0.1 201940 14704 ?        Sl   avr08   0:00 python3 /usr/lib/software-properties/software-properties-dbus
emmanuel 32301  0.0  0.0  14264   944 pts/18   S+   13:11   0:00 grep --color=auto software

$ killall gnome-software
```